# Bash script for MQTT

Tags: bash, mqtt

I'm new to the above topics and struggling to find the necessary material I need. I've a task to complete where I need to publish from my broker (raspberry pi 3) to a client also a (raspberry pi 3) through a zip file and unzip it at the 
Client side, through base64(encoder/decoder). I am able to do this through ssh no problem but I'm unsure the protocol for implementation in MQTT. Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Are trying to send zip file through MQTT across your raspberry pi ?

Comment: Just stating a list of requirements and expecting somebody to write it for you is not how StackOverflow works. You need to show us what you have tried and explain why it doesn't work and somebody will help you fix it. Please read the doc on asking a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry if it came across that way, i'm looking for advice on the problem not someone to write it for me.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to convert the zip file encoded using base 64 to binary format

2) You can publish the binary data to any topic in MQTT.

3) Another client subscribed to this topic must get the binary data and then convert to back to the zip format.

The limitation of pay load size allowed through mqtt is **256 MB**. So first make sure your zip file is less than the limit specified.